# Aggregation over a spark stream

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, streaming, aggregation

I am new to Apache Spark.

My Scala code is consuming JSON messages as strings from a Kafka topic in Apache Spark.

Now I want to aggregate over a certain field in my JSON. What are my options?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

You can put the JSON in a dataframe/dataset and perform the following aggregate operations.

- groupBy
- groupByKey
- rollup
- cube

Spark SQL can automatically infer the schema of a JSON dataset and load it as a Dataset[Row]. This conversion can be done using SparkSession.read.json() on either an RDD of String, or a JSON file.

```
val json_path = "dir/example.json"
val jsonDF = spark.read.json(json_path)
jsonDF.groupBy("col1").count().show()
```

Comment: thanks @Arvind .. that works for me... now there is another challenge. I want an average of a particular numeric field over the whole batch interval but the data in that time windows is split into multiple RDDs. And I can do all these compulations over foreachRDD.. is there a way I can apply something on all RDDs together?

Comment: You can Union All all the RDD's or Dataframes, register it as Temp table and perform SQL's to do Aggregated operations.